# JavaFX Game Not Displaying Properly

Tags: java, image, button, javafx, textbox

my program is having a JavaFx issue. My code runs but only the "Shuffle" button appears in the window. None of my text boxes or other buttons or cards are appearing. I'm not sure why I'm having this issue I am not getting any runtime errors or compile errors. Could anyone offer some assistance? Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
            });
      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);

      HBox center = new HBox(10);
      Card card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);

      Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(2));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);

      Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(3));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);

      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      LinkedList<Object> expInput = new LinkedList<>();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();
      char tempStor[] = str.toCharArray();
      for(char c: tempStor){
         expInput.add(c);
      }

       int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : -1;      



      expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> {
               if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3)){
                  if(express == 24){
                     result.set("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     result.set("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  result.set("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });

      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class Card extends Pane {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card){
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         cardVal = card;
      }

      public int CardValue(){
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13){
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26){
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }


         return card;
      }



   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Card` class is just an empty `Pane` with nothing added to it, so it doesn't show anything visible. Hence the `center` just contains a bunch of empty panes.

You never actually put any controls inside the `bottom` `HBox`, so that is empty too.

I do see the `Label` that says `"go."` next to the button.

Comment: I tried to add the images inside the Card pane. Do you know why they wouldn't be added?

Comment: Can you update the question and show the code where you added them?

Comment: Is this not adding them:  cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png"); ?

Comment: No, that just creates the `Image`. Scene graph nodes behave just the same as any other Java object; nothing magic happens just because you instantiate them. You need `getChildren().add(cardImage);`

Comment: I don't understand where I could put this. Would I add it to the center? And how would that work for multiple cards?

Comment: This is the error code I am getting with that: Main.java:123: error: no suitable method found for add(Image) Am I missing an import?

Comment: Oh, oops, yeah, you need an `ImageView`: `getChildren().add(new ImageView(cardImage));`

Comment: Thank you so much this worked beautifully!  The only issue now is that my shuffle button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your shuffle button shuffles the list of integers, but it doesn't change the cards that are shown... There are similar errors throughout your code. E.g. the variable `str` has to be the empty string, and so `express` has to be `-1`, so a lot of that code is not doing anything. Your text field doesn't do anything either.... I'd actually recommend you work through some of the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) before you try anything like this.

Comment: Right I know this. I'm not sure though how my shuffle error is connected at all to these other errors you are mentioning. I think the only issue I'm having with shuffling the cards is displaying the actual cards that are shuffled. Do you have any advice as to how to fix my event handler so it does this? I tried adding children but that gives me a duplicate error

Comment: Do `center.getChildren().clear()` and then add the appropriate cards?

Comment: Ah, maybe my Collections.shuffle(deck); really isn't doing anything. I did this: btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               
              center.getChildren().clear();    
              Collections.shuffle(deck);
              center.getChildren().add(card2);
                           
                
            }); And all it did was clear and card1 remained. Do I need to shuffle in a different way?

Comment: I think you really need to figure this out for yourself. Shuffling the list of integers is not going to change what `card2` is, for example.

Comment: I have searched everywhere for how to shuffle images and display them. I'm worried that I'm going to have to restructure all of my code. My question is just am I missing something simple or large here? I feel like there should be an easy way to add the images back to the pane from a button press.

Comment: I DID IT!! WOOOOO. New code: btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
              center.getChildren().clear();    
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(0)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(1)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(2)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(3)));
                          
            });
Still have a lot to do but this is a mini-victory.